# Yup: Validation with test failes

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm using yup for validating my react form.

My problem is :

I have the below schema for validating an input field.

```
object().shape({
    firstname: string()
        .required('First Name is required')
        .test('length', 'First Name must have more than 1 character', (value) => {
            console.log(value && value.length < 2 ? true : false);
            return value && value.length < 2 ? true : false;
        })
        .test('alphabets', 'Name must only contain alphabets', (value) => {
            console.log(!/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(value));
            return !/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(value);
        })
});
```

When I enter a single character it shows `Name must only contain alphabets` error message and when I try to type more characters it shows `First Name must have more than 1 character` error message.

What should I do wrong?

Anyone, please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be doing both of your validation wrong way, you want to return `true` if validation passes and `false` if validation fails.

In your first validation `value && value.length < 2 ? true : false` you are looking for `value.length > 2` instead of `<` and also no need to have ternary as comparison operator will return true/false value after evaluation.

In your second validation `!/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(value);` you are negating the validation by using `!`

Here's the corrected validation code:

```
object().shape({
    firstname: string()
        .required('First Name is required')
        .test('length', 'First Name must have more than 1 character', (value) => {
            return value && value.length > 2;
        })
        .test('alphabets', 'Name must only contain alphabets', (value) => {
            return /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(value);
        })
});
```